# Add block to form (before submit button)

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I'm having problems placing a block in my form. This is what I have now:

I have a register form and a fb button **block**. I say the block must be visible **only when page is equal to user register page**.

But the problem is that I don't want to have the form and underneath the block. I would like to add the block before the submit button of my form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. load the block content manually
2. control the order of fields withj `#weight` option

example:

```
function my_form()
{
  $block = block_load(MODULENAME, BLOCKDELTA);
  $block = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
  $block_build = _block_get_renderable_array($block);

  $form['FIELD_1'] = array(
    ...
    ...
    '#weight' => 1
  );

  $form['FIELD_2'] = array(
    ...
    ...
    '#weight' => 2
  );

  $form['FIELD_3'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="SOME_CLASS">',
    '#suffix' => '<div>',
    '#markup' => render($block_build),
    '#weight' => 3
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'OK',
    '#weight' => 4
  );

  return $form;
}
```

if those forms are from other modules you can alter them with [hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function.

example:

```
function MYMODULE_OR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // dpm($form_id);
  if ('user_register_form' == $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['#weight'] = 50;

    $block = block_load(MODULENAME, BLOCKDELTA);
    $block = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
    $block_build = _block_get_renderable_array($block);

    $form['fb_field'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="SOME_CLASS">',
      '#suffix' => '<div>',
      '#markup' => render($block_build),
      '#weight' => 49
    );
  }
}
```